# Rails4 has_many through with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many

I have a `has_many through` association as follows:

```
has_many :bookmarks, -> {where('actions.bookmark=true')},
    :through => :actions,
    :source => :object
```

what I'd like to do is to extend the above to pass categories for the objects bookmarked. Something like the following:

```
has_many :bookmarks, -> (category) {where('actions.bookmark=true and objects.category=?', category)},
    :through => :actions,
    :source => :object
```

I was hoping it would allow me to do queries such as `user.bookmarks("papers")`. However, when I try the above, `category` takes on the value of `#<User:0x000001017f2090>` (basically `user` in the call above) and I don't seem to be able to call the association with a simple string.

Any suggestion on how this could be achieved? Thanks very much.

Comment: I see that in your `where` query, you're passing in `cat` instead of `category`.  Was that just for the sake of brevity in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be achieved in the `has_many` call. I'd just define an instance method in my `User` class to get that functionality:

```
def bookmarks_for_category(category)
  bookmarks.includes(:objects).where('objects.category = ?', category)
end
```

Not sure about the implementation of this method, but the point is that I don't think you can have a `has_many` that accepts parameters.

Another thing you could look into is [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes). In this case you may want to define a `for_category` scope on your `Bookmark` model, allowing something like:

```
user.bookmarks.for_category('papers')
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I did think of doing this, but it has a problem. Bookmarks need to be paginated and also I tend to handle pagination in my controller (I am using `kaminari`).

Converting it to an instance method doesn't allow for pagination I believe. And even if I find a work around, I need to push down my pagination to the model which is not desirable. Thoguhts?

Comment: Well, afaik you can just pass a limit and an offset to a scope: `user.bookmarks.for_category('papers').limit(x).offset(y)`

Comment: Actually this should also work for the instance method, since `where` will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` upon which you can add more calls like `limit` and `offset`. So if you implement that method in your `User` class, you can do this in your controller to get your pagination working: `user.bookmarks_for_category('papers').limit(x).offset(y)`

Comment: yup you are right. I think a `scope` is a better idea maybe so I am going to stick to that. But thanks for the help! That solved it :)

Comment: Yeah I agree, the scope looks better. You're welcome.