# What does ActiveRecord do with arguments passed in to association attribute methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

After being interested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173236/rails4-has-many-through-with-parameters), I was doing some research on how ActiveRecord defines association attribute methods.  I noticed that in the Rails console, if I have for example an instance of `Chapter` which `has_many :videos`, I get the following behavior when I pass in various arguments to `chapter.videos`.  I attempted to track down how attribute methods are defined in the ActiveRecord source code but I was having a hard time following along.

```
> chapter.videos
  Video Load (0.5ms) SELECT `videos`.* FROM `videos` ...
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [videos...]>
```

Calling a second time seems to have cached/remembered the videos

```
> chapter.videos
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [videos...]>
```

Passing in false makes no difference, it uses the cache as well

```
> chapter.videos(false)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [videos...]>
```

However, passing in anything truthy ALWAYS queries the database

```
> chapter.videos(true)
  Video Load (0.5ms) SELECT `videos`.* FROM `videos` ...
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [videos...]>

> chapter.videos(42)
  Video Load (0.5ms) SELECT `videos`.* FROM `videos` ...
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [videos...]>

> chapter.videos("hello")
  Video Load (0.5ms) SELECT `videos`.* FROM `videos` ...
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [videos...]>
```

What is ActiveRecord doing behind the scenes here with those parameters?  Does anyone know where in the source code this is happening and how, or if this is just some Ruby feature that reloads a cached attribute when something truthy is passed in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: This is deprecated in Rails 5, to be removed in 5.1. Now you should use `chapter.videos.reload` instead of `chapter.videos(true)`.  From [the changelog](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md):

> Deprecate force association reload by passing a truthy argument to
>   association method.
>
> For collection association, you can call #reload on association proxy
>   to force a reload:
>
> ```
> @user.posts.reload   # Instead of @user.posts(true)
> ```

On a related note, in the same changelog:

> Introduce `Model#reload_<association>` to bring back the behavior of `Article.category(true)` where category is a singular association.
>
> The force reloading of the association reader was deprecated in #20888. Unfortunately the suggested alternative of `article.reload.category` does not expose the same behavior.
>
> This patch adds a reader method with the prefix `reload_` for singular associations. This method has the same semantics as passing true to the association reader used to have.

Comment: There's a gem that reintroduces the argument-based syntax for force-reloading associations called [`rails-force-reload`](https://github.com/battlebrisket/rails-force-reload).

Answer (score 3):

Yes - passing something truthy tells activerecord to reload the association cache. This is documented - [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) under caching.

Unless you pass true, rails will use the cached version of the association (except if you call `count` which always hits the database)

It's also worth noting that some methods (eg `first`, `last`, `include?`) will never cause the association to be loaded. For example first will query just the first item of the association and this does not populate the cache

The bit that defines the association accessor methods is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb). You can see that it just delegates to the `reader` method on the association.

For a collection association this ends up in [collection_association.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb) where you can see that the argument to the reader is called "force_reload". The code in there is hopefully straightforward.

For singular associations there is analogous code in singular_association.rb